# How to interpret these set theory statements of generalized intersection and union?

Tags: set-theory

How do you interpret these statements of set theory, please? I understand what General union and intersections are, but the following expressions seem to introduce the type X for them and need clarification why the union equals X and the intersection to the empty set.

$\cup$[X]$\emptyset$ = $\emptyset$

$\cap$[X]$\emptyset$ = X

Comment: What's the context? Your text seems like you're asking about the statements $X\cup \varnothing = X$ and $X\cap \varnothing = \varnothing$, but that's not what your notation says.

Comment: @AmaanM thank you, but unfortunately, it is not that simple. It is from page 92 of the book "The Z Notation"(https://books.google.ca/books/about/The_Z_Notation.html?id=wa1QAAAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) page 92. Generalized Union / Intersection. the [X] means "generic set X", and my understanding is that it is to type the empty set (making it "an empty set of type X"). It is stated under "Laws", so there is no example context to provide, unfortunately.

Comment: Latex tip: union and intersection are written `\cup` and `\cap` resp.

Comment: I think the idea is that you should think of $X$ as the "universe", so that the first identity says that the union of all things in the empty set is empty and the intersection of all things  in the empty set is the whole universe $X$.